# Adding padding to p tag not working, while it does with a class

Tags: html, css

When I include padding in the `<p>` tag it’s not working. However when I try to add it on the feature-box class it works perfectly.

```html
<section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4 ">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check "></i>
          <h3>Easy to use</h3>
          <p >So easy to use, even your dog< could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3 >Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p >We have all the dogs the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's lifeyour money back.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear but try to add this to your css:

```
p {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, maybe you need some padding top and bottom your p tag, then add my code it will work perfectly...

```
p{
  padding: 20px 0;
}

   <div class="feature-box col-lg-4 ">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check "></i>
        <h3>Easy to use</h3>
        <p >So easy to use, even your dog< could do it.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye"></i>
        <h3 >Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p >We have all the dogs the greatest dogs.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work</h3>
        <p>Find the love of your dog's lifeyour money back.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below code:

```css
.feature-box p {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4 ">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check "></i>
          <h3>Easy to use</h3>
          <p >So easy to use, even your dog< could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3 >Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p >We have all the dogs the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's lifeyour money back.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code below:

```css
p {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section id="features">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check"></i>
          <h3>Easy to use</h3>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bullseye"></i>
          <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
          <p>We have all the dogs the greatest dogs.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i>
          <h3>Guaranteed to work</h3>
          <p>Find the love of your dog's lifeyour money back.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```